# scrollbars appearing on my html page

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

hopefully this is an easy one. I've got scrollbars appearing on my web page when viewed in chrome. I think it's a padding or margin issue but I haven't been able to get it sorted. Can someone take a look please?

My css:

```
.sub-news {width: 750px; margin: 0 0 20px 0px; padding: 0 0 0 10px; clear: both; overflow: auto; }
.sub-news h3 {font-size: 1em; margin: 5px 0 0 0;}
.sub-news a {background-color: #f39200; padding: 5px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.sub-news img {width: 220px; height: 127px;}
.sub-news p {width: 220px;}

.first-sub-news, .second-sub-news, .third-sub-news {width: 240px; float: left; overflow: auto;}
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dstewart101/YeVXm/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: auto;` CSS property from the `.first-sub-news` class.

Also on the `.sub-news` class if you don't want that to scroll either.

Note: `overflow: auto;` will  automatically add scroll bars if the content within is greater than the defined height or width.

Comment: many thanks. never ceases to amaze how helpful people are here!

Answer (score 3):

The CSS property `overflow` determines what happens to the text that doesn't fit inside the default area. Having it set to auto means that if it goes out of the boundaries, it will have a scrollbar, otherwise it will not. The other possible settings for this are:

```
overflow: visible;  /* Appears over the top of other elements on the page */
overflow: hidden;   /* Anything outside gets cut off */
overflow: auto;     /* Scroll bars appear if needed */
overflow: scroll    /* Scrollbar will always be present, even if there is nothing to scroll */
overflow: inherit;  /* Same as parent */
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your `overflow:auto`s from .sub-news and .first-sub-news

http://jsfiddle.net/YeVXm/1/